# Is it possible to make interactive push notification in a hybrid ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I've recently made a hybrid app using cordova and ionic. As a feature of this app i would like to provide interactive push notifications. Is it possible to provide this in a hybrid app? if so could you please direct me towards tutorials that help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but I tested this fork which works !

https://github.com/elizabethrego/cordova-plugin-local-notifications